# What should be on your "Going Live Day" checklist?

Tags: deployment, production

Aside from the technical specifics, what should be on your checklist for when you go live with a program? **Are there last minute things you can do to make a piece of software go into production smoothly?** (assuming you used sound principles in development and tested the average amount) More testing? Discussion with the client? Last minute optimizations?

Comment: It depends on the software, and what "go into production" means.  However, NEVER, repeat NEVER do last-minute optimizations just before putting something into production.  There should have been a freeze for some time for the purpose of fixing bugs ONLY.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure today isn't Friday.

Never push code into production on a Friday. :)

Comment: Actually, I don't know about that. In many industries, its common to push code on Friday evenings or Saturday mornings as transaction volumes are lower, and you have more time to rollback if things don't go as planned.

Answer (score 1):

There's no *going live day*. There is a going live **process**. Depending on the kind of software, you could deploy to selected beta testers first (Google-style), and expand the user base.

The same applies if the software is replacing manual processes.

If the software is replacing another system, it is harder, and you should should plan for simultaneous operation of both systems, until there is enough confidence in that the old system can be turned off.

At any rate, you should expect problems, so it is best to have a thorough risk assessment with ready-to-go mitigation and contingency strategies. The risk of an all-or-nothing launch plan is too high.

Comment: For some things, it's a going-live day (or maybe weekend).  In many cases, it isn't feasible to have parallel production systems.

Comment: @David Thornley: "In many cases, it isn't feasible to have parallel production systems".  I don't know what the risk mitigation strategy is, then.  However, we do several "cut-overs" from old production to new test.  At some point, the users would rather use new test because it works better.  We do one more "cut-over" and decommission the old production.  Often by and domain name change only.

Comment: @S.Lott:  The risk mitigation strategy is to try really hard to make it go smoothly, and fall back entirely on the old system if necessary.  I don't see how to do it differently in, say, a transaction-based system with considerably different data formats.

Comment: @David Thornley: The run-both-in-parallel is one of those things that's been used for decades. Even with considerably different data formats.  However, the "multiple cut-over" works pretty well, even if the data formats are different.  It's one direction only, so it's easy to get right.

Comment: @S.Lott:  Running in parallel, or multiple cut-over, means that input from both the old and new versions has to go into both the old and new data stores, since for the applications I'm thinking about it's mandatory that the information be kept complete and consistent.  That's more code that has to be written and tested and which can cause problems during the cutover.  It can't be one direction only without a simultaneous rollout everywhere.

Comment: @David Thornley: A lot of hypotheticals.  All possibly valid at one time or another.  And all reinforcing this answer's point that "go live" is a process not a moment.

Comment: @S.Lott:  A lot of facts for some systems my wife's been involved in, actually, meaning that "go live" has a moment of switchover.  It's quite likely that your shop is a lot more organized than where my wife works, and it may be that you're working to different requirements.  What do you do for staged cutovers when everybody has to be working from the same consistent collection of data?

Comment: @David Thornley: To have a consistent collection of data, we use "multiple cut-over".  It works pretty well, even if the data formats are different. It's one direction only, so it's easy to get right.

Comment: @S.Lott:  For everybody to be working on the same collection of data, some on the old and some on the new, it can't possibly be one direction only.  Stuff done on the new system has to show up on the old.  This is the point I don't see you addressing, and what's stopped my wife's shop from staged cutovers.

Comment: @David Thornley: I'm sure your situation is somehow unique.  "Stuff done on the new system has to show up on the old." is a strange assumption, but if it's true, then it's true.  Everyone I've ever worked with has managed to cope with the parallel thing by careful management.  I've only been doing this for a few decades, so I guess I've still got a lot to learn about situations where management doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @David "means that input from both the old and new versions has to go into both the old and new data stores" the input from the old system must be fed to the new system several times before the new system can go into production. That code better be well tested. With the code done, it's a manageable step to keep running to synchronize the systems during the deployment process.

Comment: @S.Lott:  "Stuff done on the new system has to show up on the old" isn't an assumption, it's a consequence of everybody needing to be using the same data in a staged rollout.  Either there's one big cutover, or it's necessary to feed stuff from the new system back to the old, either programmatically or by doing it twice.  I've observed this happening where my wife works, and to be honest the management there might not be the best, but I don't see how better management would solve the problem.

Comment: @David Thornley: "everybody needing to be using the same data in a staged rollout" is not the same thing as a complex bidirectional flow.  It can be, and clearly, you feel that bidirectional is very important.  It's also possible to have unidirectional flow (from old to new) and people working on new.  People who know something that makes their life easy.  They know they're parallel testing and they know that work will get discarded in the new system.  I've observed this being done -- time and agin -- over the last few decades.  It is a real scenario that people really chose.

Comment: @David As @Lott suggests, the old system can be shut down in phases. Attempting shut down of a large part of the old system is OK, as long as you have a tested strategy in place to roll back the upgrade. The risk of not managing the risk is an undefined amount of lost business, while the risk of considering all problem scenarios should be manageable percent of the cost of developing the new system.

Comment: @David As to the need to feed data both ways, logic says that if you're ready to switch systems in single day, you're also ready to have degraded functionality (things not showing up) in the old system. Risk-wise, if something goes wrong with the new system, you would indeed have to copy any data entered into it to the old system. Since that code has to be written and tested for a contingency, why not make it part of the deployment plan from the start?

Comment: @Apalala:  I have no idea why you think one mass cutover means readiness for degraded functionality.  The idea of the mass cutover is to avoid degraded functionality, as one system will always be running more or less properly.  The emergency plan is usually to fall back on the old system, and everybody re-enters what they did (if the fallback is before anybody actually uses the new system, there's no problem).  It isn't a great emergency plan, but if the conversion has been done properly it isn't likely to be needed, and it prevents catastrophic failure.  That is risk management.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a fairly generic question, so of course I'm going to have to reply with a generic answer.  My opinion is that it's safe to assume that there will most definitely be problems with your software, so what you should plan for on "Going Live Day" aside from making it available for download is this.

Be ready to correct critical errors within the first couple weeks of going live with someone dedicated to the task.  When the critical errors are fixed, you can begin to handle the major errors.  :)

Answer (score 0):

As other answerers have noted, it's so high-level a question it's hard to answer very specifically. I will just say this: it's long-standing web developer's superstition that a web site launched on a Friday will never get an audience or produce any ROI. A friday afternoon launch is especially the kiss of death.

At this point, I'm happy to say 100% of my clients have bought into this superstition.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there last minute things you can do to make a piece of software go into production smoothly?

No.

There are no last-minute things.  There can't be.

First you get it to work, securely, quickly, and reliably.

Once it's working, you introduce it to users.  Perhaps as a pilot or alpha-test.

Then, after you make needed enhancements, you introduce more users.  Perhaps as a beta-test.

Then, after you make needed enhancements, you introduce more users.

There's no moment at which you "go live".

You progressively introduce more users.